# Why does spring security allow an anonymous user to submit a request?

Tags: spring-security

I make blog on Spring Security.

I write this code in configure():

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/*","/user/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/*").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/register", "/auth").hasRole("ANONYMOUS")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Controller code for creating a post

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/user/create_post")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Posts posts,@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails customUserDetails)
    {
        postService.create(posts, customUserDetails.getUsername());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

However, when an unauthorized user tries to create a post, then in customUserDetails Null is passed.

Why does spring security not issue Forbidden and prevent the user from sending a request?

Comment: why are you doing this stuff?
.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()

Comment: It was just like that in the tutorial, I don't know exactly what it is for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you have not told spring to authenticate all other requests.

you must add for example:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
```

for example in your code:

```
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/admin/*","/user/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
.antMatchers("/user/*").hasRole("USER")
.antMatchers("/register", "/auth").hasRole("ANONYMOUS")
.anyRequest()
.authenticated()
```

All this is fully documented in the api documentation for `HttpSecurity`.

[Spring security documentation HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-httpsecurity)